# UIView returning wrong values for height with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I have a custom UIView which draws a "ring" progress into it with the help of `CAShapleLayer`and `UIBezierPath`. When drawing the bezier path into the view I want to draw it into the center of the view. My view has the auto layout contrains leading and trailing from it's superview and aspect ration 1:1 (so that it's a perfect square).

My first idea was that I'll just get the sizes (height and width) of the view, divide by 2, make a CGPoint and use it with the bezier path. With my logic that would return the exact middle of the view wouldn't it?

Apparently not. In the log the view returns 497 for its height and width, the view debugger tells me it's 303 and the view looks like this:

[image: Totally wrong CALayer]

Has anyone and idea why this is happening?

Comment: Post your autolayout code

Comment: Looks size class related. Where are you logging the height from. Needs to be after `viewWillAppear` has run. If you change the constraints you will also need to request layout. Can you show your code?

Comment: I set it via the interface builder. Leading space: 35, trailing space: 35 and aspect ration view.height = view.width  / 1:1

Comment: Well Any/Any size is 600x600, so taking away your 70 margin and guessing you constrained relative to margins (2x16) this gives a view width of 498. On iPhone 6, the width is 414pts: so subtracting 102 this gives you 312. These numbers are close to what you put in the question which implies you must be logging before the view layout has occurred relative to the device screen size but in the debugger after layout has occurred. The black view looks right. From the circle, my guess is you set the circle center and radius before layout so are drawing where you would draw if the device was 600x600.

Comment: Rory means you're checking the view height and width before the view has been resized for display.  Are you checking it in viewDidLoad?